# sql bcp export error

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL bcp "select * from dbo.table1" queryout "Z:\test.csv"  -T -c -S ".\SQL2012EXPRESS"
```

I got error saying: Incorrect syntax near 'select * from dbo.table1'.

I wonder what's the problem?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: I added, but still get the same error?

Answer (score -1):

Include the database name as well in your select query like below

```
bcp "select * from db_name.dbo.table1" queryout "Z:\test.csv"  -T -c -S ".\SQL2012EXPRESS"
```

Also, since you are getting entire table data `select * from ...` you can just do

```
bcp db_name.dbo.table1 out "Z:\test.csv" -T -c
```

**EDIT:**

I have a DB named `test` in which have a table named `test1`. If I try below it complain nothing. Just open a command prompt and run the `bcp` command

```
C:\Users\blah>bcp test.dbo.test1 out "D:\test.csv" -T -c

Starting copy...

1 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1      Average : (1000.00 rows per sec.)
```

Comment: sorry, I tried your query but still it doesn't work? I tried bcp db_name.dbo.table1 out "Z:\test.csv" -T -c then it says Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: @user3344443, that's wired cause I tried myself before posting and it works fine. See edited answer. You must be doing something wrong.